# Delay state check inside Flutter bloc listener

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm sending data to the server via a bloc and showing a `progressSnackBar` during, and then a `successSnackBar` on success. Sometimes this takes less than a second and it makes sense to not show the `progressSnackBar` at all - in other words ***wait a second and then check if the state is still `UpdatingAccount`***. I've tried and failed with different combinations involving `Future.delay(...)` and I can probably do a `setState` hack but is there a way to achieve this just inside the bloc listener?

```
BlocListener<AccountBloc, AccountState>(
  listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
    if (state is UpdatingAccount) { // <-- delay this
      Scaffold.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(progressSnackBar());
    } else if (state is AccountUpdated) {
      Scaffold.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(successSnackBar());
    }
  },
  // rest...
),
```

Comment: Could you have instead put the 1 second wait logic in your BLOC? You could yield UpdatingAccount twice and tack in elapsed time so your listener can decide if progress should be shown. Then just omit the second yield if the process is done under 1 second. Or is flow control like that within the BLOC considered bad practice? I'm still somewhat new to the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up making the widget stateful and giving it an `_updated` *bool* member.

```
BlocListener<AccountBloc, AccountState>(
  listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
    if (state is UpdatingAccount) {
      _updated = false;
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        if (!_updated) {
          Scaffold.of(context)
            ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
            ..showSnackBar(progressSnackBar());
        }
      });
    } else if (state is AccountUpdated) {
      _updated = true;
      Scaffold.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(successSnackBar());
    }
  },
  // rest...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Future.delay()` in your `state is UpdatingAccount` condition and check state again.

```
if (state is UpdatingAccount) { 
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
    if(state is "UpdatingAccount"){
      Scaffold.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(progressSnackBar());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, `Future.delay()`ing doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply use Future.delayed()**

> Here the sample code emit state after some delay verify its should ***await***

```
if (event is LoadDataEvent) {
  emit(LoadingState());
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  emit(SuccessState());
}
```